# The document has no catalog object (meaning: it's an invalid PDF)

Tags: c#, itext

I am reading and writing to the same PDF at the same time i am getting error "The document has no catalog object (meaning: it's an invalid PDF)" on this line "PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputPdf2);" in the below code snippet.

```
       iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy pdfCopy = null;
        Document finalPDF = new Document();
         //pdfReader = null;
        FileStream fileStream = null;
        int pageCount = 1;
        int TotalPages = 20;
        try
        {
            fileStream = new FileStream(finalPDFFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            pdfCopy = new PdfCopy(finalPDF, fileStream);
            finalPDF.Open();              
                foreach (string inputPdf1 in inputPDFFiles)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(inputPdf1))
                    {
                        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputPdf1);
                        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(bytes);
                        fileStream = new FileStream(inputPdf1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
                        var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, fileStream);
                        var acroFields = stamper.AcroFields;

                            stamper.AcroFields.SetField(acrofiled.Key, "Page " + 1+ " of " + 16);

                        stamper.FormFlattening = true;
                        stamper.Close();
                        stamper.Dispose();
                        fileStream.Close();
                        fileStream.Dispose();
                        pdfReader.Close();
                        pdfReader.Dispose();
                    }
                }

            foreach (string inputPdf2 in inputPDFFiles)
            {
                if (File.Exists(inputPdf2))
                {                        
                    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputPdf2);
                    int pageNumbers = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
                    for (int pages = 1; pages <= pageNumbers; pages++)
                    {
                        PdfImportedPage page = pdfCopy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, pages);
                        PdfCopy.PageStamp pageStamp = pdfCopy.CreatePageStamp(page);
                        pdfCopy.AddPage(page);
                    }
                    pdfReader.Close();
                    pdfReader.Dispose();
                }
            }
            pdfCopy.Close();
            pdfCopy.Dispose();
            finalPDF.Close();
            finalPDF.Dispose();
            fileStream.Close();
            fileStream.Dispose();
```

please help me in order to fix issue or give me any alternate approach

Answer (score 1):

In your first loop you overwrite each of your files with a manipulated version like this:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputPdf1);
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(bytes);
fileStream = new FileStream(inputPdf1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, fileStream);
[...]
```

**Using `FileMode.Open` here is an error.** You want to replace the existing file with a new one, and for such a use case you have to use `FileMode.Create` or `FileMode.Truncate`.

Using `FileMode.Open` results in the original file content remaining there and you writing into it. Thus, if your new file content is shorter than the original one (which can happen when flattening a form), your new file keeps a tail segment of the original file. In PDFs there are relevant lookup information at the end, so upon reading this new file the `PdfReader` finds the lookup information of the old file which don't match the new content anymore at all.

---

By the way, you create the `PdfCopy` like this:

```
fileStream = new FileStream(finalPDFFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
pdfCopy = new PdfCopy(finalPDF, fileStream);
```

This is wrong for the same reason: If there already is PDF there, `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` works just like `FileMode.Open` with the unwanted effects described above.

---

Thus, you should replace the `FileMode` values for streams you write to with `FileMode.Create`.